# Twitter sdk wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I'm looking for an twitter sdk for windows phone 8.
I already tried twitterrt. And it's working well for metro app but not for windows phone 8.
I was looking for rewrite the sdk but there aren't `WebAuthenticationBroker`, `CryptographicBuffer`, etc in wp8.

So my question is : Is there an twitter sdk for windows phone 8 or should I rewrite the sdk ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TweetSharp is the most popular Twitter SDK on Windows Phone and seems to work just fine on WP8. Check out the project web site @ https://github.com/danielcrenna/tweetsharp

Here's how to install [TweetSharp from NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/TweetSharp):

> Install-Package TweetSharp

Here's a simple WP8 hello world code sample:

```
TwitterService service = new TwitterService("<my app key>", "<my app secret>");
service.GetTweet(294183806548733952, 
    (tweet, response) => Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => 
            MessageBox.Show(tweet.Text, tweet.Author.ScreenName, MessageBoxButton.OK)));
```

And when running this code snippet on the WP8 Emulator we can see the following:

[image: WP8 Emulator showing TweetSharp hello world messagebox]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Now I'm able to use your code. But, I can't log in using GetRequestToken(); (I got an unauthorized http status).